# XMPP Server: How to define restrictions on group members?

Tags: xmpp, messaging, openfire

The requirement is to create a group chat such that:
1. One/few members (under a defined role e.g. Admin) can send message to all participants whereas 
2. Remaining members can reply/send messages to admin members only.

From user experience viewpoint, admins should see messages posted by all group members whereas remaining members will see self posted messages &  from admin only (no messages from other group members except Admins). 
The role and group info is current defined in mySql DB that needs to be mapped with XMPP user roles/groups. Kindly advise best option to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer.  [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) details answers where User in Visitor role (section 5.1) can’t post message to all users in chat room (group) but can send private message to specific user (refer section 7.5 for example).